# adding library in pycharm editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have installed pip on Windows 10 for numpy library. Now I can import numpy library in python shell IDLE, but this library is not recognized in my PyCharm editor. How can add this library to PyCharm editor? I use python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyCharm you can go to `File > Settings` and then click on the `Project > Project Interpreter` option.
This allows you to specify which Python interpreter you plan on using and create a virtual enviornment for your project if you wish to do so.

If you click on the `+` button on this page you can add in new libraries or just verify on this page which ones are installed. Remember to do `import numpy` at the top of your script file or `import X` where 'X' is whatever additional library you want to import.